# VBA Highlighting weekly/quarterly date ranges

Tags: excel, vba

I need some help with a macro to highlight some date ranges.  I feel like it's a simple solution, but I can't wrap my brain around it.  My work follows a specific calendar of weeks, periods and quarters.  Weeks are of course 7 days from Sunday to Saturday, periods are a little different, they are exactly 4 or 5 weeks, and quarters are always 3 periods of 4 weeks, 4 weeks, 5 weeks.  I have to run a report regularly and I want to highlight each period a different color (just the HeaderRowRange).  Currently I hardcoded a dictionary with the first date of the period and the number of weeks to format them.  This is not optimal as I have to continually update the code with new dates.

[image]

So far I've figured I could set a start date of 1/1/2023 and I can divide by 91 to get the quarter and offset back from each quarter point, but I'm not sure how to handle the cells previous to the first quarter on the sheet or after the last quarter.  I keep feeling that there's another way that I'm missing as well, but my brain won't pull it up.  Does anyone have any ideas?

```
Sub Split()
    ActiveSheet.Name = "MPS"
    'Objects
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Worksheets("MPS")
    Dim tbl As ListObject: Set tbl = ws.ListObjects(1)
    tbl.Name = "Schedule"
    Dim xRng, cell As Range
    
    'Array
    Dim qtrs(1 To 4) As Range
    
    'Variables
    Dim TargetDate, StartDate As Long: StartDate = DateValue("1/1/2023")
    Dim DateFactor As Double
    Dim x As Long
    
    Set xRng = tbl.HeaderRowRange(, 3).Resize(1, lCol - 2)
    x = 1
    For Each cell In xRng
        DateFactor = (DateValue(cell) - StartDate) / 91
        On Error Resume Next
        If DateFactor = Int(DateFactor) Then
            Set qtrs(x) = cell
            x = x + 1
        End If
    Next cell

    For x = 4 To 1 Step -1
        BLARGH!

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

From the looks of it, you need each quarter to be a different color, and in your data, quarters are not just 1/1/2023 - 3/31/2023, but instead are by weeks. First 13 weeks of the year: 1st Quarter, from week 14-26 2nd quarter, 27-39 3rd, and 40-53 4th.

If this is the case, you should probably not use VBA (it is possible in VBA, and perhaps very easy) but why not use conditional formatting? example:

[image: Similar Table]

I have used the following 3 formulas in the conditional formatting which apply to =$1:$1 which is Row 1.

First quarter: `=AND(WEEKNUM(A1)<=13,A1<>"")`

Second quarter: `=AND(WEEKNUM(A1)>13,WEEKNUM(A1)<=26,A1<>"")`

Third Quarter: `=AND(WEEKNUM(A1)>26,WEEKNUM(A1)<=39,A1<>"")`

[image: Rules]

Last Formula for the 4th quarter would be:

`=AND(WEEKNUM(A1)>39,WEEKNUM(A1)<=53,A1<>"")`

Comment: Actually I need it to highlight each period(month), but your answer did lead me to a solution.  I didn't know about the WEEKNUM function and after looking into it I found one of the options was to set the first Thursday of the year as the first week, which follows our calendar.  Then I used a dictionary with the week number and how many weeks to resize it to color.  Adding that many conditional formats in VBA would be cumbersome.  Thank you though!!

Answer (score 0):

I didn't know about the WEEKNUM function which led me to a solution.

```
Sub Split()
ActiveSheet.Name = "MPS"
'Objects
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Worksheets("MPS")
Dim tbl As ListObject: Set tbl = ws.ListObjects(1)
tbl.Name = "Schedule"
Dim dict As Object: Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
Dim xRng, Cell As Range

'Variables
Dim lCol, i As Long

'builds dictionary object with the starting day of each period as key and number
'of weeks as key
dict.Add 1, 4
dict.Add 5, 4
dict.Add 9, 5
dict.Add 14, 4
dict.Add 18, 4
dict.Add 22, 5
dict.Add 27, 4
dict.Add 31, 4
dict.Add 35, 5
dict.Add 40, 4
dict.Add 44, 4
dict.Add 48, 5

'Searches the header row for dates listed in the dictionary and highlights them by
'the number of months in the period
lCol = tbl.ListColumns.Count
Set xRng = tbl.HeaderRowRange(, 4).Resize(1, lCol - 3)
x = 41
For Each Cell In xRng
    i = Application.WorksheetFunction.WeekNum(DateValue(Cell), 2)
    If dict.exists(i) Then
        Cell.Resize(, dict(i)).Interior.ColorIndex = x
        x = x + 1
    End If
Next

tbl.Range.Columns.AutoFit
```

End Sub